# Windows Azure Platform Ready Testing Tool

Tags: azure

I am running the platform ready test tool to try and qualify for the Powered By Windows Azure Logo Program.

My application is in production and has been running in azure for 5 months now.  The application consists of a windows forms and WPF Client application which connects to a set of WCF Services running in azure which in turn connects to SQL Azure.  The application also uses blob storage in Azure and I have getting on for 1TB of documents up there.

The application uses basic http binding and is configured Like this

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

I successfully passed the test for SQL Azure but failed the test for windows azure with the following message

> ======================================================================
>   Test case/Verification: TC 1 -
>   Application must be a valid Azure
>   application designed to connect with
>   or work in the Windows Azure Environment
>
> ======================================================================

Status is ProtocolError
Fail

The only thing I can think of this is causing this is that the application connects over https and the test tool does not allow me to specify a https endpoint.  However I don’t think I can easily expose a plain http endpoint just to pass the test as WCF wont allow me to do that when TransportWithMessageCredential is used.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our service AzureWatch is in the same boat. I've been in touch with MS engineers at the Ready program and they don't appear to support our precise scenario. However, they do have a version of the tool that can use https channel. I suggest contacting them via support channel. They may supply you with a later version to try, and if that fails with forms to request "bypass" of the actual testing

HTH

Comment: Thanks Igorek. That is exactly what has happened. I have just finished filling in the test waiver form. They did let me try the next version so I know the whole https area is one they are working hard on. After 5 months in production I am still in love with Windows Azure so I can't be too hard on them.